# Redirect subdomains to a new URL while retaining subdomain

Tags: nginx

I want to permanently redirect traffic from one domain to another.

Now while i know this is simple, i want the subdomain portion (wildcarded) to be the same on the new domain i redirect them to (if that makes sense)

what sort of configuration will work.. or is it even possible?

example:

```
server {
    server_name *.olddomain.com;
    rewrite ^(.*) http://*.newdomain.com$1 permanent;
}
```

I get the feeling that putting a wildcard there isnt going to work, so any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: I found a working solution here: 
[nginx redirect to another domain not forgetting about the subdomains][1]


  [1]: http://serverfault.com/questions/319627/nginx-redirect-to-another-domain-not-forgetting-about-the-subdomains

Comment: Hey bro ... you may want to answer your own question :)

Comment: I thought i did, but it hasn't closed it off.. not sure what i've done wrong!